# Can list data be displayed as table in Visual Studio source code

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a list with tuples which I'd like to display in source code more readable. The image below shows for ID 0 and 1 what I did manually. ID 2 shows, how I receive the data.
Is there a way to display such data more readable in Visual Studio without doing the manual work?

[image: list with tuples, formatted vs. not formatted]

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cpmcgrath.Codealignment

Comment: Thanks! I tested it on the [wiki example from GitHub](https://github.com/cpmcgrath/codealignment/wiki/Align-by-Comma). I selected the two lines, clicked _Align by..._ in the toolbar and executed `,\s*(?<x>[^\s])`. Only "Item 2" and "Item Two B" were aligned. What am I doing wrong?